# How to escape special characters in windows command line

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, escaping

I need to execute an .exe file (with two different arguments in parallel).
The execution of the EXE file works like this:

```
C:\WorkDir> "C:\ProgramFiles\MyProgram\my.exe" "XML_PARAMETER_STRING"
```

I need to pass the XML_PARAMETER_STRING to this program from command line, which contains some special characters, like `" ' < >`

e.g.:

```
<WizardValues> <Module>D:\some path\calc.yxwz</Module> <Value name='param1'>True</Value> <Value name='param2'>2019-09</Value> </WizardValues>
```

The program execution from command line works properly if I do this:

```
C:\WorkDir> "C:\ProgramFiles\MyProgram\my.exe" "<WizardValues> <Module>"D:\some path\calc.yxwz"</Module> <Value name='param1'>True</Value> <Value name="param2">2019-08</Value> </WizardValues>"
```

... but it fails when I try something like this (to run them parallelly see the sidenote below):

escaping every special character:

```
cmd /C " ^"C:\Program Files\MyProgram\my.exe^" ^"^<WizardValues^> ^<Module^>^"D:\some path\calc.yxwz^"^</Module^> ^<Value name='param1'^>True^</Value^> ^<Value name='param2'^>2019-08^</Value^> ^</WizardValues^>^" > output.txt"
```

give as multiple arguments:

```
cmd /C "C:\Program Files\MyProgram\my.exe" "<WizardValues> <Module>"D:\some path\calc.yxwz"</Module> <Value name='param1'>True</Value> <Value name='param2'>2019-08</Value> </WizardValues>" > output.txt
```

(I've read that the **escape character** in windows command line is `^`, but it does not seem to work as expected). I get errors like this:

```
< was unexpected at this time.
```

or

```
'"D:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

**Questions:**

- What am I donig wrong?
- How could I execute both commands parallelly from command line?
- What is wrong in my solution?

**Sidenote:**

I need to start two processes from command line, each should run in parallel.
There is a need to wait until both process finishes.

The following bat file solves this problem (I'm trying to create a solution based on this, that's why I need a solution with `cmd /C "COMMAND"`):

```
(
   start "task1" cmd /C "timeout /t 5 /nobreak > nul"
   start "task2" cmd /C "timeout /t 3 /nobreak > nul"
) | pause
```

Comment: Have you opened a Command Prompt window and read the output from `cmd /?` I'm fairly sure it should explain how it handles doublequoting.

Comment: Why don't you just quote the whole XML string, like `"%ProgramFiles%\MyProgram\my.exe" "<WizardValues> <Module>D:\some path\calc.yxwz</Module> <Value name='param1'>True</Value> <Value name='param2'>2019-09</Value> </WizardValues>"`? Then, with `cmd.exe`, try this: `cmd /C ""%ProgramFiles%\MyProgram\my.exe" "(whole XML string)""` or `cmd /C "^"%ProgramFiles%\MyProgram\my.exe" "(whole XML string)"^"`. *N. B.:* The `'` is not special at all to `cmd.exe`...

Comment: The percent character isn't escaped by quoting, so there's a chance that an embedded `%<name>%` matches a `<name>` environment variable. In a batch script we can escape percent by doubling it as `%%`. At the command line and `/c`, we can break it up like `"..."%"USERNAME"%"..."`. In the initial parsing pass, CMD will try to expand an environment variable literally named `"USERNAME"`. This works as long as we don't create variables with quotes in their names. If my.exe follows VC++ rules, it will consume these double quote characters, leaving `...%USERNAME%...` as the literal argument.