# Why is here difference in this 2 cases of command execution?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command-line, escaping

I need to run two commands in paralel with double quotation (the simple one won't work in my case) and wait for the results. But when I do this, I get a different behavior with double qouted execution (my command simply won't run for unknown reason).

I've simplified the problem to this example:

```
(
   start "task1" cmd /C "timeout /t 5 /nobreak > nul"
   start "task2" cmd /C ""timeout /t 8 /nobreak > nul""
) | pause
```

You can see that in the later case the counter will count down, but not in the first case

```
Waiting for 8 seconds, press CTRL+C to quit ...
```

**Question:**

- What causes the change between those two cases?
- How can this changed behavior avoided?

---

In my special case:

When I run this everything works fine:

```
start "task1" cmd /C ""D:\Program Files\Alteryx\bin\AlteryxEngineCmd.exe" "^<WizardValues^> ^<Module^>D:\long path\aaa.yxwz^</Module^> ^<Value name='Drop Down (31)'^>2019-08^</Value^> ^</WizardValues^>" > outp1.txt "
```

When I put the simple version into a complex one the execution simply fails:

```
(
   start "task1" cmd /C ""D:\Program Files\Alteryx\bin\AlteryxEngineCmd.exe" "^<WizardValues^> ^<Module^>D:\long path\aaa.yxwz^</Module^> ^<Value name='Drop Down (12)'^>2019-08^</Value^> ^</WizardValues^>" > outp1.txt "
   start "task2" cmd /C ""D:\Program Files\Alteryx\bin\AlteryxEngineCmd.exe" "^<WizardValues^> ^<Module^>D:\long path\bbb.yxwz^</Module^> ^<Value name='Drop Down (34)'^>2019-07^</Value^> ^</WizardValues^>" > outp2.txt "
) | pause
```

Question:

- How this change in behavior is similar to the above example?

Comment: Your first example has double double quotes on the second line, making the redirect to `nul` invalid. remove the double double quote and both windows will not display the timeout.

Comment: Then for the second example, why do you want to `start` instances of `cmd`? You need to understand to which command your redirection to output will originate from. So seeing as you want to give the task names in the windows, remove `cmd /c` from the lines completely and fix your quoting.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think you didn't understood my example/intentions here. The main purpose here is not to correct the first example, but to make work the double qoutation in the second example. I need to use double qoutation due to the constraints originating from my second example (like escaping properly the XML string, passing paths containing space characters, etc.), therefore the first example is not "wrong" in that sense. To correct the second example I've no idea how to do it properly...

Comment: I've deleted the cmd /c, but the problem is thew same:
'>2019-08</Value> was unexpected at this time.

Comment: Yes, because of your quoting. I do not have your commands, but try something like `start "task2" "D:\Program Files\Alteryx\bin\AlteryxEngineCmd.exe" ^"^<WizardValues^> ^<Module^>D:\long path\bbb.yxwz^</Module^> ^<Value name='Drop Down (34)'^>2019-07^</Value^> ^</WizardValues^>^" ^> outp2.txt`

Comment: as for the first command, it is wrong. you're adding the correct quotes on the first line which is correct. on the second line you are adding double double quotes, this opens and closes and open closes. Because you are redirecting to nul, your second command does not redirect because of the quotation issues, where the first does not have the issue and redirects correctly to nul

Comment: I've rewritten your example to mine, but it seems to fail the same way as before..
`start "task1" "D:\Program Files\Alteryx\bin\AlteryxEngineCmd.exe" ^"^<WizardValues^> ^<Module^>D:\New Developments\aaa.yxwz^</Module^> ^<Value name='Drop Down (3)'^>2019-08^</Value^> ^</WizardValues^>^" ^> outp1.txt`
The error message is: `'>2019-08</Value> was unexpected at this time.`
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: remove the escape from the `^> outp1.txt`

Comment: I get the same result...

Comment: let me try and replicate your executable scenario.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to escape special characters in windows command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57887232/how-to-escape-special-characters-in-windows-command-line)

Comment: @Compo This another question was asked by me, it's not closely related to the topic (I just use the same example from there). In that other questionI was asking for how to escape this properly (the answer was double quoting), not how the double qoutation changes the behavior...

Comment: @GerhardBarnard This seems to run, but produces no output into the file: `start "task2" "D:\Program Files\Alteryx\bin\AlteryxEngineCmd.exe" ^"^<WizardValues^> ^<Module^>D:\long path\aaa.yxwz^</Module^> ^<Value name='Drop Down (15)'^>2019-07^</Value^> ^</WizardValues^>^" > outp2.txt`

Comment: @GerhardBarnard This seems to fail: `(
   start "task1" "D:\Program Files\Alteryx\bin\AlteryxEngineCmd.exe" ^"^<WizardValues^> ^<Module^>D:\long path\aaa.yxwz^</Module^> ^<Value name='Drop Down (15)'^>2019-08^</Value^> ^</WizardValues^>^" > outp1.txt
   start "task2" "D:\Program Files\Alteryx\bin\AlteryxEngineCmd.exe" ^"^<WizardValues^> ^<Module^>D:\long path\aaa.yxwz^</Module^> ^<Value name='Drop Down (15)'^>2019-07^</Value^> ^</WizardValues^>^" > outp2.txt
) | pause` with error message: `'>2019-08</Value> was unexpected at this time.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concerning your test scenario:

In `cmd /C "timeout /t 5 /nobreak > nul"` the [redirection operator `>`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) is hidden from the hosting [`cmd`](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html) instance (the one that runs the code of your batch file), so it becomes executed in the inner `cmd` instance.

In `cmd /C ""timeout /t 5 /nobreak > nul""` the `>` is exposed to the hosting `cmd` instance, so redirection is executed there and the inner one does not receive the `> nul` part.
(Though what surprises me a bit is that no syntax error arises due to the double-quotation; I could imagine that the second `start` command actually receives something like `""timeout /t 5 /nobreak` to execute, where it seems to remove the leading `""` from, but I am not quite sure.)

---

Concerning your special case:

Forget about [escaping](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) within your XML-like string, just escape the outer quotes and the redirection operator.

- Running the program alone:

  ```cmd
  start "task1" cmd /C ^""D:\Program Files\Alteryx\bin\AlteryxEngineCmd.exe" "<WizardValues> <Module>D:\long path\aaa.yxwz</Module> <Value name='Drop Down (31)'>2019-08</Value> </WizardValues>" ^> "outp1.txt"^"
  ```
- Running the program in the pipe (`|`) requires double-escaping, since either side is executed by `cmd /S /D /c` on its own here:

  ```cmd
  (
      start "task1" cmd /C ^^^""D:\Program Files\Alteryx\bin\AlteryxEngineCmd.exe" "<WizardValues> <Module>D:\long path\aaa.yxwz</Module> <Value name='Drop Down (12)'>2019-08</Value> </WizardValues>" ^^^> "outp1.txt"^^^"
      start "task2" cmd /C ^^^""D:\Program Files\Alteryx\bin\AlteryxEngineCmd.exe" "<WizardValues> <Module>D:\long path\bbb.yxwz</Module> <Value name='Drop Down (34)'>2019-07</Value> </WizardValues>" ^^^> "outp2.txt"^^^"
  ) | pause ^> nul
  ```

Unfortunately you cannot just omit the (escaped) outer pair of quotation marks, because `cmd` is not quite intelligent when handling them. Something like `cmd /C "program.exe" "quoted string"` leaves the command line `program.exe" "quoted string` behind, which is of course invalid syntax.

*N. B.:*
Usually an external program can be started using without `cmd /C`, but in your situation you are using output redirection `>`, which is a thing internal to `cmd`, that is why you need it.